# Dropdown list contains Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create dropdown list with image or icon for each option

```
<select>
  <option>*Image1 TextOption1</option>
  <option>*Image2 TextOption2</option>
.
.

  <option>*ImageN TextOptionN</option>
</select>
```

Can somebody please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI's [.selectmenu()](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render) is your best choice in my opinion. most common and plenty of examples online

Here is an example right from jQuery website:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
        _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
          var li = $("<li>", {
            text: item.label
          });

          if (item.disabled) {
            li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
          }

          $("<span>", {
              style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
              "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
            })
            .appendTo(li);

          return li.appendTo(ul);
        }
      });

      $("#filesA")
        .iconselectmenu()
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
        .addClass("ui-menu-icons");

      $("#filesB")
        .iconselectmenu()
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
        .addClass("ui-menu-icons customicons");

      $("#people")
        .iconselectmenu()
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
        .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    h2 {
      margin: 30px 0 0 0
    }
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
    }
    select {
      width: 200px;
    }
    /* select with custom icons */
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      top: 0.1em;
    }
    .ui-icon.video {
      background: url("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/selectmenu/images/24-video-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.podcast {
      background: url("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/selectmenu/images/24-podcast-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.rss {
      background: url("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/selectmenu/images/24-rss-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    /* select with CSS avatar icons */
    option.avatar {
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .avatar .ui-icon {
      background-position: left top;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="demo">

    <form action="#">
      <h2>Selectmenu with framework icons</h2>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="filesA">Select a File:</label>
        <select name="filesA" id="filesA">
          <option value="jquery" data-class="ui-icon-script">jQuery.js</option>
          <option value="jquerylogo" data-class="ui-icon-image">jQuery Logo</option>
          <option value="jqueryui" data-class="ui-icon-script">ui.jQuery.js</option>
          <option value="jqueryuilogo" selected="selected" data-class="ui-icon-image">jQuery UI Logo</option>
          <option value="somefile" disabled="disabled" data-class="ui-icon-help">Some unknown file</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <h2>Selectmenu with custom icon images</h2>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="filesB">Select a podcast:</label>
        <select name="filesB" id="filesB">
          <option value="mypodcast" data-class="podcast">John Resig Podcast</option>
          <option value="myvideo" data-class="video">Scott González Video</option>
          <option value="myrss" data-class="rss">jQuery RSS XML</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <h2>Selectmenu with custom avatar 16x16 images as CSS background</h2>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="people">Select a Person:</label>
        <select name="people" id="people">
          <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">John Resig</option>
          <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
          <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```